# Ninject injection not working on subclasses

Tags: asp.net, repository, ninject, ninject.web

I'm trying to add a binding on third level sub-class but I can't find a proper way to do it. I'm using the Ninject 3.0 and I have following scenario:

```
public class ClassBase 
{
  [Inject]
  public IRepository RepositoryInstance { get; set; }
}

public class ClassA : ClassBase {} 
public class ClassB : ClassA {}

public class RepA : IRepository {}
public class RepB : IRepository {}
```

How do I bind the RepA to ClassBase so ClassA can have that repository, while ClassB should be bound to RepB ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You might use `WhenInjectedInto()` ninject `IBindingWhenSyntax<T>` interface.

So, the binding code will look something like

```
kernel.Bind<IRepository>().To<RepA>().WhenInjectedInto<ClassA>();
kernel.Bind<IRepository>().To<RepB>().WhenInjectedInto<ClassB>();
```

Comment: You mean WhenInjected*Exactly*Into, don't you?

Answer (score -1):

As far a I remember, the Inject attribute is deprecated and should not be used. I would use a constructor to inject it or in specific class I wolud use this kind of method
IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
var samurai = kernel.Get();

as showed here: https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Dependency-Injection-With-Ninject

Comment: +0 Generally ctor injection is going to give a better result, so why not point that out in a comment. You havent addresed the question itself so it doesnt count as an answer for me.

Comment: Are you sure that the Inject attribute is deprecated ?